# Using enum in @Url.Action() routevalues

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

This question is just a quick one. I have a set of links on a page, and they all actually point to the same controller method - the difference between them is that they each pass a different value to that method so that the subsequent process is slightly different. I happened to already have an enum defined to correspond to the possible values passed, so without thinking, I did this:

```
@Url.Action("QueryStepTwo", new { type = QueryType.UserRecords })
```

and was pleasantly surprised to see that nothing gained a red underline. I hit compile and navigated to that page to verify, to be presented with an error message for CS0103: "The name 'QueryType' does not exist in the current context". In the editor, `QueryType` is syntax-highlighted and IntelliSense provides the options list when I type it.

I'm assuming this is just a case of VS/IntelliSense being just a little bit too smart and knowing things that the actual page parse/render engine can't? Casting the enum to its string or int value doesn't help, so I'm guessing this is to do with the order in which things are executed; more specifically, the enum is out of scope by the time Razor gets to see the page. Is there a way to use an enum in URL helpers like this, especially one that doesn't require the enum to be defined as a member of the view model? I dislike using magic strings all over the place; they're too vulnerable to typos and tomfoolery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you fully qualify the namespace where this enum is defined:

```
@Url.Action("QueryStepTwo", new { type = SomeNamespace.QueryType.UserRecords })
```

or if you don't want to do that you could also add an `@using`  directive to the top of your Razor view:

```
@using SomeNamespace
```

And if you want to do this globally for all Razor views you could add this namespace to the `<namespaces>` node in `~/Views/web.config` (not to be confused with `~/web.config`):

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        <add namespace="SomeNamespace" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

As far as the Intellisense in Razor views is concerned, this is not something that could be trusted. Hopefully Microsoft will improve it in future versions.

Comment: The `@using` directive is already there; without it I don't get the highlighting or IntelliSense. How odd.

Comment: Typical Visual Studio problem: stop dev server process, clean, rebuild, run again... and the problem disappears. Something somewhere must have been cached, or something. If there's one thing Microsoft need to fix, it's the way VS introduces non-existent errors like that. Anyways, your answer is technically correct, so you get the accept :P

Comment: And yet in my case, casting is exactly what I needed. e.g. `...new { actionid = (int)MerchantActionIds.ChangePin, varid = 0 })` When the Enum was called, say, MyEnum.ChangePassword, I was getting "ChangePassword" where I wanted its numeric value. (`/controller/action/ChangePassword/0` instead of `/controller/action/200/0`)